# iOS9 Untrusted Enterprise Developer Pop Up

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode7, ios9

I got my device updated to iOS9 beta, but when installing an app on the device, it is displaying a popup with an error.

In iOS9, there is no option to trust an enterprise build. Has anyone found a workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just figured this out for iOS 9:

**Settings >> General >> Profile**

You should see the app listed at that screen. Tap on it.
Tap "Trust (name here)".

It should work.
It's working for me.

**With IOS 15**, now this option appear little different but you can find it at below path :

Got to **General > VPN & Device Management > click on profile which is associated with your app.**

Answer (score 1):

Do like this：

[image]

Go to Settings - General - Profiles - tap on your Profile - tap on Trust button.

Answer (score 0):

In IOS 15.6 go to general/VPN and Device management/ there u see the trust button just click there and u r done. Hope this will help u thanks